# In the Jenkins API is there a way to find the git commit of the last build?

Tags: git, jenkins

I would like to write a script to automate the feature branch creation for hot-fixes. In order to do that I need to figure out how to see what was the last commit in the current build.

Is there a way to get the last commit from the Jenkins API?

```
git checkout -b hotfix <commit>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not specify which API would you prefer to use.
But assuming Jenkins XML API it would be something like:

```
http://myjenkins/job/myJobName/lastBuild/api/xml?xpath=//lastBuiltRevision/SHA1
```

Comment: Does the `lastBuiltRevision` refer to the commit hash that was built in the *previous* Jenkins build? I am looking for a way to determine if my pipeline should rebuild the app it's deploying, or take an existing build from a previous run. We're using pipelines, which the Git plugin doesn't support yet, otherwise I'd use the `GIT_LAST_COMMIT` provided by the plugin. So i'm wondering if i can compare the current revision with the `lasBuiltRevision`, and build if they differ. I could conceivably check for 'Started by Github Push by', but I think that might be less reliable.

Comment: The `lastBuiltRevision` refers to the last commit that was built by the build pointed by the URI (in this case `lastBuilt`). You could use the XML API this way to workaround the issue. But while you are writing groovy anyway, you could use a helper function like this: `def getLastSuccesfulSHA1() {
    def b = currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousSuccessfulBuild()
    return b.getAction(hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildData.class).lastBuiltRevision.sha1String
}
`