# Last successful build's revision for an upstream MultiBranch Job in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'd like to get the build revisions of the last successful builds of Upstream jobs. The upstream jobs are multibranch jobs.

So far I'm generating a list of upstream jobs' names as triggers. But I can't seem to find the right method to call.

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def upstreamPackages = ['foo', 'bar']
def upstreamJobs = upstreamPackages.collect { "${it}-multibranch/master" }.join(',')

pipeline {
    agent none

    triggers {
        upstream(upstreamProjects: upstreamJobs,
             threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
    }

    stages {
        stage('test'){
            steps{
                script {
                    upstreamJobs.each {
                        println it
                        job = Jenkins.instance.getItem(it)
                        job.getLastSuccessfulBuild()

                        revision = job.getLastSuccessfulBuild().changeset[0].revision
                        println revision
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This results in a null object for `item`. What's the correct way to do this?

**UPDATE 1**
After discovering the Jenkins Script Console and this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162539/in-the-jenkins-api-is-there-a-way-to-find-the-git-commit-of-the-last-build#comment67012509_36163642), I managed to come up with the folllowing:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildData

def upstreamPackages = ['foo', 'bar']
def upstreamJobsList = upstreamPackages.collect { "${it}-multibranch/master" }.join(',')

@NonCPS
def resolveRequirementsIn(packages){
    BASE_URL = 'git@github.com:myorg'
    requirementsIn = ''

    packages.each { pkg ->
        revision = getLastSuccessfulBuildRevision("${pkg}-multibranch")
        requirementsIn <<= "-e git+${BASE_URL}/${pkg}.git@${revision}#egg=${pkg}\n"
    }

    println requirementsIn
    return requirementsIn
}

@NonCPS
def getLastSuccessfulBuildRevision(jobName){
    project = Jenkins.instance.getItem(jobName)
    masterJob = project.getAllItems().find { job -> job.getName() == 'master' }

    build = masterJob.getLastSuccessfulBuild()
    return build.getAction(BuildData.class).getLastBuiltRevision().sha1String
}


pipeline {
    agent { label 'ci_agent' }

    triggers {
        upstream(upstreamProjects: upstreamJobsList,
             threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
    }

    stages {
        stage('Get artifacts'){
            steps{
                script{
                    requirementsIn = resolveRequirementsIn upstreamPackages
                    writeFile file: 'requirements.in', text: requirementsIn
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's throwing an error:

```
an exception which occurred:
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.withscript.WithScriptScript.script
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.LabelScript@56d1724
    in field groovy.lang.Closure.delegate
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@27378d57
    in field groovy.lang.Closure.delegate
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@6e6c3c4e
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.closures
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@5d0ffef3
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@5d0ffef3
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: 
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Jenkins' Pipeline DSL requires all assigned objects to be Serializable.

`Jenkins.instance.getItem(jobName)` returns a `WorkflowMultiBranchProject` which is not Serializable. Neither is `Jenkins.instance.getItem(jobName).getItem('master')` which is a `WorkflowJob` object.

So I invariably went down the call chain to what I needed replacing variable assignments with chained method calls and came up with the following solution.

```
def upstreamPackages = ['foo', 'bar']
def upstreamJobsList = upstreamPackages.collect { "${it}-multibranch/master" }.join(',')

def String requirementsInFrom(packages){
    final BASE_URL = 'git@github.com:myorg'
    requirementsIn = ''

    packages.each{ pkg ->
    revision = Jenkins.instance.getItem("${pkg}-multibranch")
        .getItem('master')
        .getLastSuccessfulBuild()
        .getAction(BuildData.class)
        .getLastBuiltRevision()
        .sha1String

        requirementsIn <<= "-e git+${BASE_URL}/${pkg}.git@${revision}#egg=${pkg}\n"
    }

    return requirementsIn.toString()
}
```